# Page refresh alternates my actual page with a blank page in Chrome

Tags: php, html, ajax, google-chrome

I have a file uploader created in an html form that uses AJAX and PHP to upload the file. This is working just fine. On success, the filename is added as an option to a select object to create a list of files. However, when I click on the refresh button, a white screen is shown. When I refresh again, it goes back to the uploader screen. The console shows an empty html for the blank page. For more information, this is only happening on chrome, which would probably suggest a cache problem. But when I hard reset, it goes back to alternating. I added the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

but this seems to be having no success. Finally, I am doing this development locally through XAMPP. Error reporting is on in php.ini, and set to all.

Comment: Try add unique GET parameter for location of redirection

Comment: @Deep what do you mean?